# Spring repository for super entity class not fetching all subclass entity types when changed from @MappedSuperClass to @Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, repository

We have an abstract `@MappedSuperClass` and bunch of entities extending it, like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SuperEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

and lots of entities like:

```
@Entity
public class Sub[1..20]Entity extends SuperEntity {
   ...
}
```

Because of this there were created - as well - a bunch of repositories for each entity. All well this far.

Now there is a need to fetch all the entities that extend super. Therefore `SuperEntity` was changed as below:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class SuperEntity implements Serializable {
```

This should be functionally almost the same (is it?).

Then a new repository for this was created, like:

```
public interface SuperEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SuperEntity, Long> { };
```

Now the problem is, when calling:

```
superEntityRepository.findAll();
```

it returns only about 5 of sub entities not all the 20. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Upon writing the question I realized what was the problem. Values - including IDs - were inserted straight to the database and IDs were not unique in the scope of `SuperEntity`. That is why there is no `@GeneratedValue`, BTW. IDs were only unique in the scope of each extending sub class entity.

There were no error messages. Spring repository just picked up the first found id and all the other entities with same ID were ignored.

So the **answer** to have this working is to to update all the extending entities to have unique ID in the scope of the `SuperEntity`.

However, updating references cascading is quite a job so if there is a lighter way to get this working, share it.

*Yes, I could have deleted the question but maybe someone finds it and this answer useful*